# Unity3d - what is linecast hit.normal

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, raycasting

I'm trying to understand what does `hit.normal` return from linecast.
This is simple method to checking slope limit for character, the only thing i want to know is `hit.normal` what is it?

---

```
private void check_slope_limit() {
    // Var
    var hit_angle = 0f;

    // Raycast
    RaycastHit hit;

    // Line of direction: if hit ground layer
    if (
        Physics.Linecast(transform.position + Vector3.up, transform.position + direction.normalized, out hit, ground_layer)
    ){
        hit_angle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, hit.normal);

        var target_point = hit.point + direction.normalized;

        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position + Vector3.up, transform.position + direction.normalized, Color.yellow);

        if (
            hit_angle > slope_limit 
            &&
            Physics.Linecast(transform.position + Vector3.up, target_point, out hit, ground_layer)
        ){
            if (hit_angle > slope_limit){
                move = false;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    move = true;
}
```

---

[image]

---

I really hate do something without understanding

Comment: Please try to limit questions to asking [one specific question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) I've edited the question to abide by that rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the **[normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry))** of the surface at the hit point:

[image: diagram of hit normal]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but why purple line(normal) above why it is not below. and please can i draw normal line inside unity editor ?

Comment: The "below" normal would simply be that normal + 180 degrees.

Comment: @DerekC. oh thank so much :) but can/how drow line, i mean something like this - Debug.DrawLine(hit.poin, TO, Color.red); ???

Comment: @Mr.Ali Try `Debug.DrawLine(hit.point, hit.point + hit.normal * 5f, Color.red);`

Comment: Try looking at the doc page for it, there is an example of that. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D-normal.html